# Tell iOS *which* WiFI BSSID to join when there are multiple

Tags: ios, wifi

Imagine you're at a hotel with a poorly-designed wireless network, but you happen to have a network analyzer with you. You discover that they have tons of access points with the same name, but far-and-away the strongest ones are:

- Channel 1 @ -60 dBm
- Channel 6 @ -65 dBm
- Channel 1 @ -65 dBm

Obviously, the best one to connect to is the Channel 6 one...

But a naive algorithm is likely to pick Channel 1.

How do I convince iOS to connect to the Channel 6 one and not the Channel 1 one?